# I can not call my new form in my program after i created it

Tags: c#

I have no idea about how this error was made. Here's my code and error.
I created a new form in solution explorer and wrote these codes in my main form. I'm sure that the hitbox which I used below is right.

```
 public partial class HomePageForm : Form
 {
    OptionsPageForm frmOptions;
 }
 private void HomePageForm_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     if (this.homePageOptionsButtonHitBox.Contains(e.Location))
     {
         this.Enabled = false;
         frmOptions = new OptionsPageForm(this);
         frmOptions.Show();
     }
 }
```

And these are codes i wrote in my "frmOptions" - which is the form i want to call.

```
public partial class OptionsPageForm : Form
{
    OptionsPageForm frmHomePage;

    public OptionsPageForm(HomePageForm frmCreator)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frmHomePage =frmCreator;
    }
}
```

The error given by visual studio is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type "My Application_.MainPageForm" to "My Application_.OptionsPageForm".

And this is another form-calling I did in this application, it has the same structure as my call to `frmOptionsPage`, but it works perfectly.

```
public partial class HomePageForm : Form
{
    GamePageForm frmGame;
}
private void HomePageForm_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.homePageStartButtonHitBox.Contains(e.Location))
    {
         this.Hide();
         frmGame = new GamePageForm(this);
         frmGame.Show();
    }
}
```

(In Gamepage form)

```
public partial class GamePageForm : Form
{
    HomePageForm frmHomePage;

    public GamePageForm(HomePageForm frmCreator)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frmHomePage = frmCreator;
    }
}
```

I now really want to get some help, please.

Comment: Inside your `OptionsPageForm` change `OptionsPageForm frmHomePage;` to `HomePageForm frmHomePage;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move you Mouse Click event handler into the class like this

```
public partial class HomePageForm : Form
{
    GamePageForm frmGame;

    private void HomePageForm_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
         if (this.homePageStartButtonHitBox.Contains(e.Location))
        {
             this.Hide();
             frmGame = new GamePageForm(this);
             frmGame.Show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, it's my copy-and-paste fault. I wrote correctly in this structure well in my application.